# Why I get BrokenProcessPool for the first submit, Python 3.8.3, Windows 10?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I try to write my first multiprocessing Python program. The problem is why the first `submit()` returns an already broken Future. According to the debugger the problem is set in `_start_new_thread()` (threading.py line 852), which is probably a C module, I can't debug it. Questions:

- What I'm doing wrong, how to fix this little script?
- Where can I find any message, info, why the first `submit()` returns an already broken Future?

**Additional info:** I tried to run similar little scripts from the Internet. All failed in the same way, which elimited that the problem is in the script.
I switched to Python 3.8.4 32 bit (is 64 bit available somewhere?). All these little scripts failed in the same way, which, looks like, points to Windows 10. Any hint what can I do (beside switch to Ubuntu)?

```
import sys
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
breakpoint()
## START ### THIS WILL RUN IN A SEPARATE PROCESS ###
def Proc(n):
    return n+100
## E N D ### THIS WILL RUN IN A SEPARATE PROCESS ###
def main():
    futures = [] # submit() returns stored here         
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
        for i in range(10):
            f = executor.submit(Proc, i) # <<<=== Broken
            futures.append(f)
    for i in range(len(futures)):
        if futures[i].done():
            m = futures[i].result() # It will not wait
            sys.stderr.write(f" Proc returned {m=}\n")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What did you mean by broken ?

Comment: When any script, mine at line 12, calls `submit()` it will go to process.py line 611. The submit function at line 636 creates f, which is a Future, state=pending; at line 645 there is a call `_start_queue_management_thread()`, which is at line 573. In this function at line 596 there is a call `self._queue_management_thread.start()`, this function is in threading.py line 834. In this start() function at line 852 there is a call `_start_new_thread()`. Before this call f (Future) is fine after the call "state=finished raised BrokenProcessPool". I have no information why?

Comment: Did you try without breakpoint() statement ?

Comment: Without the breakpoint my little script does work, BUT other demo scripts, which are identical from the multiprocessing point of view, are still failing with BrokenProcessPool.

Comment: I installed 3.8.5 64bit on Windows 10. Now the little scripts are working without breakpoint and failing with breakpoint. Thanks Alex for the tip. Should this behavior at least documented?

Answer (score 1):

You can not debug a multiprocessing script using `breakpoint()` as Alex suggested. If using the debugger, even the first `submit()` fails.